# How to Detect if an Android Phone have Internet Access EVEN when the Mobile Data is turn ON

Tags: android

i am working on app that must have an internet connection before populating data from the server . I have a bool method that check if the there is a network connection available but it is not working properly.

**Here is what is what to Achieve:**

1: Check if Wifi Network is Available and there is a network Access

2: Check is the Mobile Data is Enable and there is a Network Access

**Problem(Bug) :**

Currently, i do not have an internet access but my Mobile data is ON , instead of getting a Toast message that i am not connected to the internet, it will still tell me that i have an internet access but i cannot access the internet.

I have check every other possible means but they all have an approach related to the method i am using.

**QUESTION:**
How can i test if there is an Active Internet Access even if the Mobile Data is **Enable** .

MY CODE:

```
private boolean haveConnected() {
        //Vars
        boolean wifiIsConnected = false;
        boolean mobileDataIsConnected = false;
        State checkMobile;
        State checkWifi;
        ConnectivityManager connectManager;

    //init  
        connectManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        checkMobile = connectManager.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
        checkWifi = connectManager.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();

        if (checkMobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            mobileDataIsConnected = true;
        } else if (checkWifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            wifiIsConnected = true;

        }
        return wifiIsConnected || mobileDataIsConnected;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717749/check-for-active-internet-connection-android

Comment: I think you cannot do it directly. You have to make a request and get a valid response to be sure the internet connection is active

Comment: Tried such but crashed>>

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `BroadcastReciever` and let the OS tell you when it connects/disconnects. Then, you can have a class that will keep track of those events. Here is the [official description](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges). In addition, there is a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app) that has several examples that might be helpful to you.

Comment: i have tried getting the network state from a custom receiver but the same issues, it will show connected even when i do not have an active internet access..

Comment: It works if implemented properly. Another helpful link is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546712/unfortunately-app-is-getting-stopped-while-checking-for-network/15546897#15546897

Comment: All those questions are answered, if you are having the same problem please check for the solution. If it isn't the same problem, post your code so we can take a look at what you're doing.

Comment: BUT IT CHECKED ONLY MOBILE DATA?  NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

Comment: `NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(); networkAvailable = activeNetworkInfo == null ? false : activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();`

Comment: `public class UpdateReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {
 public static boolean isConnected1;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     
          ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
                                       context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
          NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          boolean networkAvailable = activeNetInfo == null ? false : activeNetInfo.isConnected();
            isConnected1=networkAvailable;
        }
    }`

Comment: I'd use `isConnected1 = activeNetInfo == null ? false : activeNetInfo.isConnected(); ` Otherwise, this should work.

Comment: Looks fine, if it works, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: keep in mind that your receiver wont get work properly when you first run the app. It would only work when the connectivity changes while your app is already running.

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple request to anywhere in the internet, if it reaches the request you have data ,else you get timeout

Comment: i guess a simple pin with 2-3 sec is also ok , try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905358/how-to-ping-external-ip-from-java-android

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for active networks:

```
    ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    networkAvailable = activeNetworkInfo != null;

    if (!networkAvailable) { 
        //do your logic
    }
```

Comment: This is simpler solution which can work, too. I would change one line though:   `networkAvailable = activeNetworkInfo == null ? false : activeNetworkingInfo.isConnected();` as per the documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo())