# Exchanging data between raspberry pi and mobile

Tags: android, file-upload, raspberry-pi3

How can I send files from my mobile phone to raspberry pi using wifi or any other network?

Comment: you may use mqtt to do all kinds of communication between different devices

Comment: I want to send files from my Android phone to raspberry pi and that file has to be displayed on the led screen connected to the pi. Can I do this using wifi? Or mqtt?

Comment: don't confuse wifi with transfer protocol... wifi is a communication link... upon wifi you are supposed to use some sort of protocol to perform actual data transmission and for that purpose i suggested mqtt as it's simple and flexible. If you want, you may also use tcp socket to perform data transmission, but then it's upto you

Comment: Okay. So I can send files through mqtt from my Android phone to raspberry pi 3?

Comment: yes, but you need to write server/client implementations, where your device acting as client and raspberry-pi as server... also make sure to install mosquitto (mqtt broker) on rpi

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a connection through sockets. 
This would require you to have a wifi dongle for your raspberry pi.

You could start with reading [Android sockets](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) and basically any tutorial you can google ([Example](http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2013/12/implement-socket-on-android-to.html))

Comment: How can I do it using only wifi?

Comment: You want it to only work if your mobile phone has wifi connection and not when you are on mobile data. This is what you mean right?

Comment: No. I want to be able to send data from mobile network or wifi. I just want to send files to pi and it has to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Anyway, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35995735/5786565) is something you might wanna take a look at.  @SaumikBhattacharya is showing how he can check whether or not you are on wifi or mobile internet

Comment: If either wifi or mobile internet is fine, then you don't need to worry about it. you only would need to add a permission to your AndroidManifest.xml '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />'

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks. By the way I'm doing a project on IOT called "Digital notice board" using pi. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you specify the question a little bit more?

Comment: The pi is connected to a led screen. And i need to send data from my Android phone to raspberry pi which has to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Specify "Any ideas". It could be a lot of different things. "Any cool ideas i could add" , "Any ideas on what i could use to accomplish a given goal" etc etc

Comment: You could use something like Phidgets to measure data. These result can be send with and displayed on the LED screen. Even a camera would be cool. Show a live stream :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

i used a server in between for communication (xmpp protocol between server and mobile)

Followed this code
    https://github.com/upnpforum/uca-android-controller/tree/master/controllerapp/src/com/comarch/android/upnp/ibcdemo

Comment: Can we send video and audio files using this?

Comment: if you want to send image/videos then solution i given is not ideal to use

Comment: Thanks. By the way I'm doing a project on IOT called "Digital notice board" using pi. Any ideas?